# Data Storage issue - Alternative for Data Storage out there?

Tags: data

in our Org, we exceed the limit of data storage regularly, we already bought expensive additional storage volume.
I am wondering, if there are any alternative to archive or store external with access from salesforce for following objects:
-campaign
-campaign members
-Email Messages
-Tasks
-Individual email results

Thanks a lot for your opinions...

Ralf

Answer (score 1):

*2019 Update:*

Salesforce has introduced Big Objects few releases back which provides cheap storage for archived records in SF. It gives consitent performance whether you have 1 million records, 100 million, or even 1 billion.

If there are any alternative to archive or store external with access from salesforce for following objects: -campaign -campaign members -Email Messages -Tasks -Individual email results ?
Yes you have to create custom Big Objects, copy data from Salesforce Sobject and store in Big Objects and delete the existing records. I cant give you exact number but big object storage was 1/4th cost of Data-Storage.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm

Answer (score 0):

One of the options I can imagine would be to create some remote service that could fetch the data via Salesforce APIs and store it locally on some server. Then, when needed, the stored data could be send back to Salesforce on demand. I would also include some mechanism in Apex for searching and querying the remote storage. There would have to be some search functionality by the remote service side - I would use C# linq, or store the objects in some noSQL database and query it with it's API.

Although there might be some Out of the box solutions I don't know about, this approach seems pretty flexible for me.

Comment: There's an expensive new feature that allows you to connect to remote objects and use them as if they were native objects, Lightning Connect. But that is only worth it if it saves you storage costs more than it costs.

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2015, this was not an option, but now you could use a tool we created at Connecting Software and solve this problem for good.

We made this tool, called **Document Extractor**, available in 2019. It monitors documents related to Salesforce accounts, contacts, leads, opportunities, quotes, contracts, orders, assets, and email messages.

Once users upload a file to Salesforce, it is detected by the service running in the background, which sends a copy of the uploaded file to SharePoint. Next, a link file pointing to that SharePoint location is created in Salesforce. The original file in Salesforce is deleted, thus saving storage space. As the link is left where the file was, it is seamless for the end user.

More details at https://www.connecting-software.com/document-extractor/ and there are some [real-world use cases](https://www.connecting-software.com/salesforce-success-stories/) also available. We can also look it up at AppExchange.

Comment: This feels like self-promotion. You need to disclose your affiliation to any links that you provide, otherwise it is spam.

Comment: Adjusted the text @DerekF, I hope the affiliation is clear now. This is not meant as spam, the tool can help a person with the problem described